# CSS height adjust

Tags: css, html

I'm building a site that has 3 sections in the middle that all sit side by side.
The center box is where the page's content will be shown and therefore will adjust to fit.

The issue is that the #leftnav and #rightnav should adjust to the height of the parent container, this would work when the #centralcontent height is adjusted by its content (text and so on) - how is this best done?

Please see the code in action: http://jsfiddle.net/AlexHighHigh/WJKR5/

Here's the HTML

```
<div id="pagecontainer">
<div id="header"><img src="http://s23.postimg.org/u4fk339vf/design_1_01.jpg" width="850" height="308" alt="logo" /></div>

<div id="centralcontainer">
<div id="leftbar">&nbsp;</div>
<div id="centralcontent">
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
  <p>&nbsp;</p>
</div>
<div id="rightbar">&nbsp;</div>
</div>

<div id="footer"><img src="http://s23.postimg.org/w6g1hc7uj/design_1_05.jpg" width="850" height="30" alt="footer" /><br />
&copy; 2014 Surrey Hills Fox Control</div>
</div>
```

..and here's the CSS

```
body {
font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background: #161616;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
color: #fff;
}
#pagecontainer {
height: 100%;
width: 850px;
margin: 0 auto; /* the auto value on the sides, coupled with the width, centers the layout. It is not needed if you set the .container's width to 100%. */

}
#header {
height: 308px;
background-color:#66CCFF;
}
#centralcontainer {
height: auto;
width: 850px;
}
#leftbar {
float: left;
width: 85px;
min-height: 100%;
background-image:url(http://s23.postimg.org/69md4q46z/design_1_02.jpg);
bottom: 0;
background-color:#66CCFF;
}
#centralcontent {
float: left;
height: auto;
width: 680px;
background-color:#FFF;
}
#rightbar {
float: left;
width: 85px;
min-height: 100%;
background-image:url(http://s23.postimg.org/lxnkbijsr/design_1_04.jpg);
bottom: 0;
background-color:#66CCFF;
}
#footer {
float: left;
width: 850px;
height: 150px;
text-align:center;
}
```

Any help appreciated, thanks in advance!
Alex

Comment: project solved, thanks all for the input and quick responses - its greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add `height: 100%;` to `body` and it would work

**why it works??** your `#pagecontainer` has `height:100%`, so it would set 100% *of* the parent of pagecontainer, which is body, but you have not set height of `body`

**EDIT**

I see you used `floats`, if its fine with you, use `display :table` as it helps you avoid `clear`ing the `float`s and other stuffs
 [**see demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/WJKR5/3/)

```
body {
    font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #161616;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: #fff;
    height : 100%;
}
#pagecontainer {
    height: 100%;
    width: 850px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    /* the auto value on the sides, coupled with the width, centers the layout. It is not needed if you set the .container's width to 100%. */
}
#header {
    height: 308px;
    background-color:#66CCFF;
    border:1px solid #FFF;
}
#centralcontainer {
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 850px;
    display:table;
}
#leftbar {
    display:table-cell;
    width: 85px;
    min-height: 100%;
    height:100%;
    background-image:url(http://s23.postimg.org/69md4q46z/design_1_02.jpg);
    bottom: 0;
    background-color:#66CCFF;
    border:1px solid #FFF;
}
#centralcontent {
    display:table-cell;
    height: 100%;
    width: 680px;
    <!-- background-color:#FFF;
    /*commented*/
    -->
}
#rightbar {
    display:table-cell;
    width: 85px;
    min-height: 100%;
    background-image:url(http://s23.postimg.org/lxnkbijsr/design_1_04.jpg);
    background-color:#66CCFF;
}
#footer {
    float: left;
    width: 850px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the speedy reply but unfortunately not, the **#pagecontainer** is working well but it's the content within **#centralcontainer** that needs to adjust to 100% of the **#centralcontainer** size  (which will have adjusted to the height of **#centralcontent**).

Please check the JS Fiddle link - http://jsfiddle.net/AlexHighHigh/WJKR5/

Comment: @AlexHighHigh : edited answer....i'll suggest you to use `table`s as it is much easier to maintain and provides compatibility with IE8+ :)

Comment: thanks, I was looking to stick to div's and learn them correctly rather than bodge it with a table. Tables are easy but a little old school.

Comment: @AlexHighHigh : i think u misunderstood my answer....please take a look again at `display` properties in my answer, its `css table` | `display:table` and not `html tables`| `<table>` :)

Comment: Thank you, I've put this in place and its working well.
I will use this rather than the other hacks suggested on the page as it is the cleanest method, legend!

Answer (score 0):

### [Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/22deL/1/)

I added a couple of other things to your CSS for better cross-browser compatibility but you can remove it if you really want.

### CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    zoom: 1;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
body {
    font: 100%/1.4 Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    background: #161616;
    color: #fff;
}
*:before, *:after {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    clear: both;
    display: table;
}
#centralcontainer div {
    outline: 3px solid red;
}
#pagecontainer {
    height: 100%;
    width: 850px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
#header {
    height: 308px;
    background-color:#66CCFF;
}
#centralcontainer {
    width: 850px;
    position: relative;
}
#leftbar {
    position: absolute;
    width: 85px;
    background-color:#66CCFF;
    background-image:url(http://s23.postimg.org/69md4q46z/design_1_02.jpg);
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
#centralcontent {
    left: 85px;
    position: relative;
    height: auto;
    width: 680px;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
#rightbar {
    position: absolute;
    width: 85px;
    background-color:#66CCFF;
    background-image:url(http://s23.postimg.org/lxnkbijsr/design_1_04.jpg);
    bottom: 0;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
}
#footer {
    float: left;
    width: 850px;
    height: 150px;
    text-align:center;
}
```

Comment: Thanks Deryck! This works very well for the height of the side bars but puts in a space above and below #centralcontainer - remove the red line and content should hopefully touch, but unfortunately this is not the case.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/22deL/1/ it needs a normalize.css / reset.css to be used.  It appears to be a browser defect.  Use this: http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/ before the other stylesheets you have.

Answer (score 0):

Hi you probably should use [common fix](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/61) for same columns height

In you case just add `overflow:hidden;` to `#centralcontainer` and to

`#leftbar,#rightbar`

add

```
padding-bottom:9000px;
margin-bottom:-9000px;
```

Please look to 
[Seems working sample](http://jsfiddle.net/WJKR5/6/)